# django-datatable-view==0.9.0 Django 3.1.3: ImportError: cannot import name 'get_datatable_structure'

Tags: django

I am using the latest package django-datatable-view 0.9.0 in django 3.1.3 (upgrading from django 1.8.6)

When a I run manage.py run server I get the following error:

```
  File "/mcvitty/mcvitty/customers/views.py", line 14, in <module>
    from datatableview.utils import get_datatable_structure
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_datatable_structure'
```

Upgrading the package is not an option as I am already using the latest package. I have searched datatableview get_datatable_structure but I cannot find it. What can I do to fix the error? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

There's a pending PR for that package to fix things for Django 3.1. https://github.com/pivotal-energy-solutions/django-datatable-view/pull/246

You'll need to either

- wait until that is merged and a new version released, or
- fork the project, merge the fixes you need, bump the version, and use that patched version as a requirement (e.g. `https://github.com/YOURGITHUBUSERNAMEHERE/django-datatable-view/archive/master.zip#egg=django-datatable-view`)